# Internationalization/localisation for environment variables arcpy GP tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, internationalization

I had gone through the below post to achieve localisation for log messages in history tool using messages.xml as well as for parameter labels using toolbox xmls.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/international-language-suppo...

But I couldn't find anything to achieve the localisation for the labels of environment  variables in the GP tool.

Any help on this?